# PowerShell splitting CSV into separate files

Tags: csv, powershell

I have a CSV file with two columns.

Sample Data:

```
Computername,Collection Name
MyServer01,NA - Data - SRV - Patching - Prod - Sat 18:00
MyServer02,NA - Data - SRV - Patching - Prod - Sat 22:00
MyServer03,NA - Data - SRV - Patching - Prod - Sat 02:00
MyServer04,NA - Data - SRV - Patching - Prod - Fri 18:00
MyServer05,NA - Data - SRV - Patching - Prod - Fri 02:00
MyServer06,NA - Data - SRV - Patching - Prod - Sun 18:00
```

I am looking to split the CSV into separate files along the collection.  As the above example, Sat 18:00

So far I have the code:

```
$data=Import-Csv .\servers2.csv

$data | Where-Object {$_ -like '*fri*' -and $_.'Collection Name' -notmatch 'all.da.servers'} | Select ComputerName,'Collection Name'
```

The end goal is multiple text files based on the collection.  So `Servers-Fri-1800.txt` and `Fri-1800.txt`.  The server names will live in Servers*.txt and the Fri-1800.txt would contain the date in the format `12-11-15 18:00`

I wanted to ask first because something tells me this method might be horribly inefficent.  -Thanks!!

-Edit, the desired output.  **Worth noting these text files will be read by another Powershell script, hence the reason for thinking a `PSCustom` object with the filtered properties would be ideal.

`Servers-Sat-1800.txt` contains `MyServer01` and `Sat-1800.txt` contains `12-11-15 18:00`
`Servers-Sat-2200.txt` contains `MyServer02` and `Sat-2200.txt` contains `12-11-15 22:00`

-edit 2, add code preview.  Is there an easier way to accomplish this?

```
$data = import-csv .\file.csv

$data | Where-Object {$_ -like '*sat?18:00*' -and $_.'Collection Name' -notmatch 'ignore.string'} |

% {"{0}" -f $_.Computername} | out-file Servers-Sat-1800.txt
```

Comment: So the sample data that you provided is not in CSV format, and is only 1 lines so there's not a good way to determine what you want grouped on. You should really update your question to clearly give sample data, and what you would expect that sample data to be output as.

Comment: Apologies, I was rushing!  I did think up a custom object, with the properties being each individual `where-object` but I'm unsure of how that would perform.

Answer (score 3):

Try the Group-Object command.  It is made to take a big mess of objects and group them together by a common property.

I took your sample and made a few more iterations

```
PCName,Collection
MyServer01, NA - Data - SRV - Patching - Prod - Sat 18:00
MyServer02, NA - Data - SRV - Patching - Dev - Sat 18:00
MyServer03, NA - Data - SRV - Patching - Dev - Sat 18:00
MyServer04, NA - Data - SRV - Patching - Prod - Sat 18:00
MyServer05, NA - Data - SRV - Patching - Prod - Sat 20:00
MyServer06, NA - Data - SRV - Patching - Prod - Sat 20:00
```

Saved it as a CSV called T:\comps.csv.  Now, to organize into different CSVs for each collection.

```
$groups = import-csv T:\comps.csv | Group-Object -Property Collection 

ForEach ($group in $groups){
 $name = $group.Name -replace ':',''
 $group | select PCName | Export-Csv -Path "t:\$Name.csv"
}
```

Had to remove the ':' from the collection names, but the end result is a bunch of CSVs, named the right name, with the right members inside.

```
>dir t:\ *.csv

    Directory: T:\

Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name                                                                                                                             
----                -------------         ------ ----                                                                                                                             
             12/11/2015   5:16 PM            375 comps.csv                                                                                                                        
-a----       12/11/2015   5:26 PM             98 NA - Data - SRV - Patching - Dev - Sat 1800.csv                                                                                  
-a----       12/11/2015   5:26 PM             99 NA - Data - SRV - Patching - Prod - Sat 1800.csv                                                                                 
-a----       12/11/2015   5:26 PM             98 NA - Data - SRV - Patching - Prod - Sat 2000.csv  

>gc 'T:\NA - Data - SRV - Patching - Dev - Sat 1800.csv'
#TYPE Selected.System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject
"PCName"
"MyServer02"
"MyServer03"
```

Comment: Is there any peformance reasons for using `Group-Object` rather than my crude method of piping the `Import-CSV` into a `Where-Object` and filtering the results as desired?

Comment: Oh, there was nothing wrong with your approach, but I find using a purely cmdlet and pipeline based method to be more maintainable, and easier to understand later.  I compared both approaches, and the `Where-Object` method (the one you were using) was 8.3 MS, while the approach I suggested took 11.4 MS.  So, your method was actually faster!

Comment: I'm under 6 seconds for working 1220 lines, creating 22 text files.  But the code looks horrible!  Perhaps this is more a code golf type question?

Comment: @user4317867 Probably not something really appropriate for code golf. Code length, code performance, code correctness, and code readability are not necessarily related. I'd put priority on correctness first, then readability a close second.

Comment: Just to revisit this, the Prod,Cert,Dev in the collection names are not important.  I'm looking to collect ServerName, Reboot Day and Reboot Time.  This will plug into additional PowerShell code to perform the server reboots along the Day/Time.